# Is it possible to make Microsoft build.exe include sources from remote directories?

Tags: windows, build, wdk

Adding source files more than one directory away (e.g. ../../source.cpp or ../../../somewhere_else/source.cpp, vs. just source.cpp or ../source.cpp) to the SOURCES= declaration in a WDK/DDK build yields the following error:

```
Ignoring invalid directory prefix in SOURCES= entry
```

Is it possible to include remote source files in a build?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is not possible to do this directly. `build` is explicitly designed only to deal with
source code in the same or parent directory of the `sources` file. It cannot use source files from arbitrary locations. In particular, its dependency-tracking system seems unable to parse and track remote files, and therefore it explicitly checks and enforces that all files be local.

There are two common solutions:

1. Build remote code as a separate lib (either via another subproject/directory in the same `build` project, or using an independent build step).
2. Place a local stub for each remote source file which does `#include "../../remote_source.cpp`, and add this local stub to the `SOURCES=` list, instead. This will work, but `build`/`nmake` will *not* track dependencies in the `remote_source.cpp`. If `remote_source.cpp` changes, you will have to either `touch` the local proxy source, or otherwise force a rebuild (delete the local proxy obj, run `build` with `-cZ`, or otherwise).

Answer (score 1):

An alternate way is to use source.inc to include these files.

Answer (score 0):

Hate to resurrect a super old topic, but I just ran into this as well.

An alternate alternate way is to create another sources file inside that solely builds object files of the remote source, so basically a file named **somewhere_else\sources**, and give it the same intermediate directory.

Then add a 'dirs' file to your original directory and specify that remote folder inside. Then link directly to the object file by adding something like this to the original sources file:

```
$(TARGETLIBS) = $(PROJECT_OBJ_ROOT)\$(O)\source.obj
```

This way, you don't have to compile as a lib, but build treats it like one and links without any dependency checking or care of location.

***Naturally you might run into some problems if you give them the same intermediate directory and the same original source file name (source.cpp)***